# URL Rewrite 2.0 not excluding subfolder

Tags: url, iis, filter, url-rewriting

Could someone please help me to solve my problem?

I'm using ASPX files on IIS 7.5 and URL-Rewrite 2.0 to get SSL in any access condition:

www.somedomain.com -> https://www.somedomain.com

www.somedomain.com/mypage.aspx -> https://www.somedomain.com/mypage.aspx

**It's functioning perfectly.** BUT, since the page loads/plays some MP3/OGG files, I had noticed that:

1- if the page is executed in SSL, the MP3 does not play in some devices (Androids/iPhone/iPad mobile devices);

2- if the page is executed WITHOUT SSL, it occurrs normally, 100%.

So, I had tried to filter the MP3/OGG files (and also, PNG/JPG images) in URL-REWRITE to avoid their access under SSL.
My filter is:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(png|jpg|mp3|ogg)" negate="true" />
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
```

I had tried a lot of filter settings on these files, as {REQUEST_URI}, {URL}, {UNENCODED_URL} and I see that all of them are ineffective to avoid these files under SSL. I see this using MICROSOFT NETWORK MONITOR, that shows all files being loaded in port 443 (HTTPS). Another characteristic is the fact of I never see the original filenames there (the MP3 files and images). It seems everything is under SSL settings.  Another one is the fact of the MP3 does not play in SSL access and the images delay some seconds to load.

I CANNOT utilize the whole domain/folder name (like www.mydomain.com/songs/music.MP3) since I'm using JPLAYER 2.0 and I cannot set this library with the entire MP3 address (the song does not play!), but just the subfolder where they remain, like below (see mp3 and ogg tags):

```
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3:"audio/" + theSongs[0] + ".mp3",
                        ogg:"audio/" + theSongs[0] + ".ogg"
                    });

                },
                play: function () { // To avoid both jPlayers playing together.
                    $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
                },
                swfPath: "Scripts/jPlayer/",
                supplied: "mp3, ogg",
                volume: 0.25,
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
                wmode: "window"
            });
```

How to avoid this kind of behavior? I wouldn't like to put these files (MP3, OGG, JPG, PNG) in another domain to avoid URL-REWRITE to catch them. I need them in the same main project and within one of its subfolder (audio and images folders).

How to create an inbound rule to REALLY discard completely these files?
Note: if I utilize as a rule something like

```
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
```

it doesn't play (or loads) too.

I would appreciate a lot your efforts to help me in solving that problem.
Kind regards,
David